# Java: thread caches

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading about volatile keyword and multithreading. So I designed a little test case to check the working of volatile keyword. Docs say the threads may cache variables so may not be aware of changes done by other threads to the variables. My program changes the variable `isRunning`(non-volatile) but still both threads become aware of the changes to the variable and stop.

Also, does my statement `if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T")){}` make sense and work in a same way I am assuming it to work?

Here is my program:

```
/**
* This program demonstrates the use of volatile keyword.
*
* Threads might cache variables if not marked volatile. Hence, cannot see changes
*/
class volatiled implements Runnable{
  private boolean isRunning;

  public void setisRunning(boolean value){
    this.isRunning = value;
  }

  public void run(){
    while(isRunning){
      try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){
         System.out.println("Error: "+e.toString());
      }

      if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T")){
        // change is running
        this.isRunning = false;
      }

      System.out.format("Thread running: %s\n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
      if(Thread.interrupted()){
        System.out.format("Thread interrupted: %s\n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return;
      }
    }  
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){

    volatiled v = new volatiled();

    // set is running 
    v.setisRunning(true);

    Thread t = new Thread(v);
    Thread s = new Thread(v);

    // set thread names
    t.setName("T");
    s.setName("S");

    t.start();
    s.start();

    //stopThread(v);
  }

  private static void stopThread(volatiled v){
    v.setisRunning(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: try with more threads and for longer time ;) I am sure you will see some weird things, wait where is volatile attribute?

Comment: Try this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-volatile-keyword-example/ you will get more idea.

Comment: `volatile` guarantees that your program will work in a particular way, but leaving out the word `volatile` does _not_ guarantee that your program _won't_ work in the same way.  The world needs a miscreant JVM that always does the worst possible thing that the JLS permits it to do.  It would be an awesome tool for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is wrong.

"Concurrent window" is very small. In your test thread#2 can see changes from thread#1, also can not see. It is called "data race". I think for this test you need more threads and more iterations. OpenJDK uses [jcstress](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/) for such tests.

Comment: So Java Thread caches are something we can demonstrate easily or it is just a concept which is hard to test?

Comment: Cache operates at lot of level starting into CPU registry until L1/L2/L3 caches. As far as I know, JVM can omit variable read ; I don't remember where I saw it ... But you may refer to [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html).

Comment: I get it : [One common compiler optimization involves having the value read for r2 reused for r5: they are both reads of r1.x with no intervening write. This situation is shown in Table 17.4-D.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4-D)

Comment: @RajatSaxena threads doens't contains cache, Cache is CPU enity. You can read  [Shipilevs articles](http://shipilev.net/).

Comment: @grinder: thanks for the link. Other articles on the website are useful as well.